# When I draw a freehand shape in Photoshop with Pen tool and fill with Paint bucket I get a 1px clear boundary between the fill and my line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Using photoshop pen tool to draw freehand shapes I cannot get the paint bucket to fill up to the boundary line what am I missing?

Comment: Probably Tolerance but it's hard to guess on just that info.

Comment: If you are *drawing with the pen tool*, it's assumed you're creating paths.. or you at least *could* be creating paths. So.. with paths.. *why* are you using the paint bucket?? You can set fill colors for shapes drawn with the Pen Tool. There's no need to ever touch the Paint Bucket. I think you need to possibly describe the actual workflow in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop, when you use the Pen Tool or Freeform Pen Tool, in the tool options along the top, set the tool to Shape mode.

[image]

After you have finished you can change the fill or stroke colour in the tool options. There's no need to use the Bucket Fill tool.

An example

[image]